# C++ How to get the size of bitfield members?

Tags: c++

I try to get the size of a bitfield.

For example, I have got a generic handle:

```
template<size_t n, size_t m>
struct handle
{
    uint32 index : n; 
    uint32 validation : m;
}
```

Now I want to get the size of the members.

I found a macro that works when I have a `handle<16, 16>` and expands the desired members to `sizeof`. In this case, if I pass in the `index` members I get `16` as my output.

But there I would have to pass in my output variable.

Is there a way maybe with some template magic to expand directly to the desired number? So I could pass in `sizeof_bit(class, member)` and I get the `sizebit` size of this member?

Comment: sizeof(uint32) or sizeof(n) will get you the size of the member in bytes (8 bits per byte). Though you explicitly define them as 32 bits. so I'm guessing you have a different question?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: I think he wants to know the value of `n` and `m`, i.e. how many bits per bitfield. (`<nitpit>`You're not guaranteed to have exactly 8 bits per byte.`</nitpit>`)

Comment: Maybe you should share the macro that works, and identify the source of the information. There most likely isn't a way to recover the sizes of the bit-fields via `sizeof()` et al.  You probably have to capture them as part of the type -- non-bitfield members that store `n` and `m` and are initialized by the constructors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler agree with general approach, but it would be more common to store them as static members, avoiding both the per-object memory usage and construction cost....

Comment: @MadScienceDreams You can't `sizeof` a bitfield.

Comment: @TonyD: I knew there was a reason to make it a comment rather than an answer...You're right, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
template<size_t n, size_t m>
struct handle
{
    enum { index_bits = n };
    enum { validation_bits = m };
    uint32_t index : n; 
    uint32_t validation : m;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f66f893e48d829a).

If you have no control over the structure defining the bitfield, you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194422/2756719) to count the number of bits in it at run time, but it's fairly inefficient.

Comment: the macro is this

#define SIZEOF_BITFIELD(class,member,out) { \
    class tmp_;                             \
    tmp_.member = ~0;                       \
    unsigned int tmp2_ = tmp_.member;       \
    ++tmp2_;                                \
    out = log2(tmp2_);                      \
}

from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539251/getting-the-size-of-an-indiviual-field-from-a-c-struct-field/539307#539307

for sure i could save the number of bits in the handle but then storing it everytime in a handle would be very inefficient :(

Comment: @user3731014 In the code above, the `enum` members (`index_bits`, etc.) are compile-time constants and are not actually stored in `handle` objects. That's why GCC produces a "variable set but not used" warning in the linked demo code.

Comment: Okay, but can i use them in another class without overhead? Ex.: template<typename handletype> struct anything { int anarray[2 ^ handletype:: index_bits] }

Comment: @user3731014 Yes (you probably don't want to use `^` though, that's bitwise XOR).

Comment: Okay, sounds nice. Thanks! (Ah yeah you're right.. Got a bit late.)